# Javascript/Jquery Multiple elements opacity animation

Tags: jquery, animation, opacity

I'm trying to create an animation based on images inside a div. I want a third of the images to appear, then disappear, then another third of images appears, etc.
So I have divided the images into 3 different classes.

I have researched a little about it and found that the best way would be to animate opacity, as seen in this article http://www.catchmyfame.com/2010/08/31/jquery-hide-vs-fadeout-vs-animate/

The problem is when I run my code, all the animations run at once, and the images don't stay on screen for a good amount of time.
Any help going in the right direction would be appreciated.

The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/vwrwsp62/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hardware > img").css( "opacity", "0" );
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show1').animate({opacity:1}, 1000)
        }, 4000);
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show1').animate({opacity:0}, 1000)
        }, 1000);
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show2').animate({opacity:1}, 1000)
        }, 4000);
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show2').animate({opacity:0}, 1000)
        }, 1000);
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show3').animate({opacity:1}, 1000)
        }, 4000);
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show3').animate({opacity:0}, 1000)
        }, 1000);
    });
```

edit: after some input I came up with some code that works, although it ended up a little random and imprecise:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hardware > img").css( "opacity", "0" );
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.show1').animate({opacity:1}, 1000).delay(18000);
            $('.show1').delay(6000).animate({opacity:0}, 1000).delay(12000);
            $('.show2').delay(7000).animate({opacity:1}, 1000).delay(11000);
            $('.show2').delay(12000).animate({opacity:0}, 1000).delay(6000);
            $('.show3').delay(13000).animate({opacity:1}, 1000).delay(5000);
            $('.show3').delay(18000).animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: instead of using `setInterval` you can pass function to animate which will run after animation finish `$.animate({opacity:0},1000,function(){//another animate})`

Comment: sorry, that didn't really work for me. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I believe its what you want

```
$(function(){

    $('.hardware img').hide().each(function(){

        // Get the number from the img class. For show1 will be 1, for show2 will be 2 etc.

        var multiplier = $(this).prop('class').replace( /^\D+/g, '');

        // Use multiplier in delay. For show1 element will be 1000, for show 2 eill be 2000 etc.

        $(this).delay(multiplier * 1000).fadeIn().fadeOut();
    });

});
```

You can also set your images CSS to `img {display:none;}` to avoid hiding them with jquery.

Comment: it looks like some excellent code, but it's not exactly what I needed. I chose not to use fadeIn and display because it would change the layout of the image grid. And besides that, I need it to be a loop and I need the images to stay on the screen for like 5 seconds before fading out.

Comment: thanks anyway, I managed to make something close to what I wanted using the delay method which you have shown me. It didn't come out very precise, but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/xoc2s5x7/

You need to adjust the divs according to your style. The problem with the code you tried is you have the classes on the images, so one animate is changing multiple images and the callback is fired multiple times, so it looks random. You need to put your images inside divs and animate the divs instead. Just make sure you're animating a single div at a time.

```
function animateAll() {
    $(".show1").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 
    function(){$(".show1").animate({opacity:0}, 1000, 
    function(){ $(".show2").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 
    function() {$(".show2").animate({opacity:0}, 1000, 
    function(){ $(".show3").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 
    function(){$(".show3").animate({opacity:0}, 1000, 
    function(){animateAll();});}); });}); });});
};
```